# Copy database between Heroku apps using multiple URLs

Tags: postgresql, heroku, copy, database-backups, database-restore

Our database on Heroku has grown to size which requies three pgbackups URLs to download. I know how to download this database backup to local computer, merge the parts together and do restore, but what to do if I want to copy database from one Heroku app to other?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy from one application from another you should be able to fork your database across applications. You can do this with:

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:crane --fork HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_SOURCE_OF_OLD_DB_AS_URL --app newapphere
```

Comment: We have Kappa and Ronin plans.